# Persist chnages to Layout page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a `layout` page that has a `side navigation bar` and in that side navigation bar, there are a few buttons to navigate to different parts of the application. That layout is being used by some `Razor` pages in my application.

By default, in the layout navigation bar, the `Dashboard` option is selected and highlighted and that is because of the `active` class placed on it. When I click on any of the other buttons (for example Layouts) on the nav bar, a call to the controller action method is sent which returns another view using the same layout but because the page is refreshed it resets the highlighted text to default which is Dashboard.

I am trying to set the active class on the button that was clicked but due to page refresh, it is setting back to default (Dashboard).
I am trying to make the button highlight that is being clicked. I used jQuery to add an active class to it but as the page refreshes all changes are reset on the layout page. Is there any other way other than Ajax and partial views? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: seems like that should be handled via style sheet active class.  You shouldn't need any javascript/jquery for that to happen.   What does the location bar say after you click "Layouts"?  Does it match the link?

Comment: @pcalkins: I think the problem is that the page is refreshed upon post back.

Comment: ahh.. I think I misunderstood that... you might just include a script that checks window.location.href against the links.  Then set the styles accordingly.  jQuery would help you iterate.  Though it does seem like there's already a script and css bundle that's broken here.  Maybe include the relevant CSS/JS bits in your post.

Comment: Yeah @pcalkins the page is refreshed so all applied changes to CSS are reset as well. I know there are applications out there that reload the page but their layout page UI is also changed and not reset bit not sure how they achieve that.

Comment: That's OK, you'd iterate on load.... in jQuery short-hand: $(function() { ... });

Comment: Maybe you can try to pass  the selected item to action,and pass the selected item to view in action,and when reloading the page,use $(function() { ... }); to select the item passed from the action.

Comment: @YiyiYou I can do that that would be a workaround rather than a fix and it will also pollute my action methods with the extra parameter being passed that should be handled in another way. I am thinking of saving the clicked button id in the local storage and on the page reload I can get the id from there and apply the active class to that id

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things,
A)Don't do a full page reload and instead return a partial page to replace the div where you are placing your content. Then side nav bar isn't reloaded.
B)Select the active tab dynamically during load on the server. Perhaps read the requested url controller or actions.
C)Utilizing some form of breadcrumbs.

Comment: That way I would need to use partial views across all of the pages and that is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid partial views?